# How to use the same form for updating/inserting records using quickForm?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this Meteor template:

```
<template name="personalDetailsForm">

 {{> quickForm collection="PersonalDetails" id="personalDetailsForm" type="insert"}}
 {{> quickForm collection="PersonalDetails" doc=editingDoc id="personalDetailsForm" type="update"}}

</template>
```

The forms are displayed as I expect, however I just want one form. A blank form for when there is no data which does an insert when the form is submitted. Then when the form is reloaded the data previously submitted is shown on the form. If the form is then submitted again any data that has changed will be updated.

Currently the insert form is displaying and underneath it the update form is displaying, with the data that has been previously inserted. Trying to update the data on the second form doesn't work, instead it inserts a new record. This I imagine could be because the form ids are the same.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
<body>
{{#if PersonalDetails}}
    {{> personalDetailsFormUpdate}}
{{ else }}
    {{> personalDetailsFormInsert}}
{{/if}}
</body>

<template name="personalDetailsFormInsert">
 {{> quickForm collection="PersonalDetails" id="personalDetailsFormInsert" type="insert"}}
</template>


<template name="personalDetailsFormUpdate">
 {{> quickForm collection="PersonalDetails" doc=editingDoc id="personalDetailsFormUpdate" type="update"}}
</template>
```

I think this part of the documentation is what I'm looking for:

> Can I reuse the same quickForm or autoForm for both inserts and updates?
>
> Yes. Your code that flips between states should do the following in this order:
>
> ```
> Change the type attribute's value to "insert" or "update" as appropriate, probably by updating a reactive variable.
> Change the doc attribute's value to the correct document for an update or to null (or a document containing default values) for an insert, probably by updating a reactive variable.
> Call AutoForm.resetForm(formId). This will clear any existing validation errors for the form.
> ```

Can anyone provide an example of this?

Answer (score 4):

The question was asked some time ago, but I had the same issue and just solved it.

It is quite easy:

Get the context data as usual. E.g. with iron-router, build a route like:

```
Router.route('Options', {
  path: 'options',
  data: function() {
    var options = Options.findOne({owner: Meteor.userId()});
    return options;
  }
});
```

Build a new helper, that checks if the context data (this in the helper) is empty or not (example is for a global helper that works in every template):

```
UI.registerHelper("formType", function(){

  if(_.isEmpty(this)) {
    return 'insert'
  } else {
    return 'update';
  }

});
```

Setup the template with the new helper:

```
<template name="Options">
<h1>Options</h1>
{{> quickForm collection="Options" doc=this id="optionsForm" type=formType omitFields="owner"}}
</template>
```

Everything should work now. If the database doesn't give a value back, the form will automatically switch to insert. So in my example, if you open the form the first time, it will use insert. The second time, it will use update.

Comment: Thank you this is the right theory to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @peXd.  this was very helpful.  however I had an additional required field in my schema which was blocking the insert and it was silently failing to insert and since i stumbled into this solution through 8 trap doors i thought i'd post it in case it helps someone else.

i found this recommendation from aldeed [https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/199] to use this error hook in client code:

```
AutoForm.addHooks(null, {
  onError: function (name, error, template) {
     console.log(name + " error:", error);
  }
});
```

however this also failed with me saying AutoForm was not defined.  this was odd to me because aldeed:autoform was being pulled into the project as a dependency.  but just to double check i did meteor add aldeed:autoform to pull it in directly and suddenly AutoForm was available to add the hook to.